# How to reload HAProxy config on CentOS with minimal downtime?

Tags: centos, haproxy

When I change haproxy.cfg, currently I am "applying" those changes by running this command on CentOS:

```
systemctl restart haproxy
```

Is there a better way to do this on CentOS that does not involve downtime, or minimum downtime (or connection resets)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `reload` instead.

```
systemctl reload haproxy
```

Comment: Thanks - and you can confirm that reload performs this operation with zero downtime?  Can you also confirm it does not reset live TCP connections?

Comment: Is there a way to do that without `systemctl`? I use WSL and it doesn't have `systemctl`.